# Akeneo: Get attributes from a Variant group

Tags: symfony, akeneo

I want to check if some attribute values have changed after editing a Variant group in Akeneo V. 1.3.

Unfortunately I am a little bit lost: Is there a way to get from a `Pim\Bundle\CatalogBundle\Entity\Group` to the attribute values? Is there another better way to get these values of a Variant group that was edited?

I cannot even find out in which table the attribute values are stored in MySQL (I've just found `pim_catalog_product_value` for the *product* values).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's not easy to dig into this part.

The values of a variant group are not stored in the same way than the products values.

These variant group values are only used to be copied in related products and are stored in a product template.

From a product template, you can fetch the values normalized in json with

```
$group->getProductTemplate()->getValuesData()`.
```

You can take a look on ProductTemplateApplier and ProductTemplateUpdater to see how we apply variant group values on products (json format is useable almost directly with product updater).

When we edit a variant group, to be able to use the same form than for the product, we use a subscriber `TransformProductTemplateValuesSubscriber`.

It denormalizes json values to product values objects with

```
$this->denormalizer->denormalize($data->getValuesData(), 'ProductValue[]', 'json');`
```

Don't hesitate if you need any further information.